# How to check when autogrowth is done last?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

In sql server 2005, the autogrowth is enabled by size. 
Is there any way to check when autogrowth on data and log file happened last?

Comment: Take a look at [How to See Recent Autogrowth Events on Databases in SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/how-to-see-recent-autogrowth-events-on-databases-sql-server/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SSMS, right click your db, go to reports->standard reports->disk usage and look for Autogrow/Autoshrink events .

Hopefully you have the correct trace levels set up, if not you might have some issues finding out history.

Comment: Can you tell me if i change this autogrowth size? does it lock the database and block other transactions? How much time does it take?

Answer (score 18):

Here's how to do it without using the sql reports(link, followed by relevant TSQL): 
https://sqlblog.org/2007/01/11/reviewing-autogrow-events-from-the-default-trace

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
   DatabaseName,
   [FileName],
   SPID,
   Duration,
   StartTime,
   EndTime,
   FileType = CASE EventClass 
       WHEN 92 THEN 'Data'
       WHEN 93 THEN 'Log'
   END
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE
   EventClass IN (92,93)
ORDER BY
   StartTime DESC;
```