# SQL Server 2008 - Added one column and now missing a bunch of on-disk storage

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm an accidental DBA, so I'm still learning. I don't come from an IT background so metadata/how SQL Server impacts the disks, system, OS, etc is something I'm woefully ignorant about (side note: if you have any good primers to suggest, I'm all ears).

The instance that I manage is SQL Server 2008R2 with about 130 DBs. The vast majority have the exact same table structure as these DBs are used for an app that clients subscribe to.

The developers of said app added a column to the audit table. This table records a lot(but not all) of the activity in the application; therefore, the table can be quite large. Currently, there are 275,476,273 rows in these tables across the instance. The column is a numeric(3,0) type with a default value of 0. If I'm understanding what I'm reading correctly, the MOST bytes the column would take per record is 19 bytes, which would translate to ~5GBs. Seems like a lot, but OK.

The problem is that over the weekend (the same weekend this task ran, hence why this is under scrutiny), 30Gbs on that server has disappeared. I have truncated the logs and datafiles (just released the free space, not actually reorganizing, etc), but we don't seem to be getting any of this storage back. I understand that it will only release the space at the end of the file, but I still have a hard time believing that there's 25GB of allocated space just sitting there in the files waiting to be used because one column was added.

What's going on? It doens't seem like the indexes use this column.

Thanks!

Edit:To be more precise about the column being added: when the column was added, the operation checked if it existed; if it did, do nothing, if it didn't, add the column. the column was set as a NULLABLE column, but with a default of 0. So, when the column was added, all NULLs were updated to 0. Not sure if that's key, here.

Additionally, The indexes for this table don't seem to be fragmented all that much. We're talking like 15% fragmented at most, I think.

Comment: Check that DBs log-files have right size. At least they aren't bigger than data files.

Comment: All logs were truncated immediately after the operation. I just checked to be sure, and all log files are smaller than the data files.

Comment: is there a partitioning function on the table? Because I recently re-created mine with adding space for 2019 data. So, some space was used there. I'm pretty sure your not creating the partition function on same drive but does not hurt to check.

Comment: Nope, no partitions, either.

Comment: Find databases with Autogrow events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752942/how-to-check-when-autogrowth-is-done-last and then try to sort out causes